# Need to write an python function to resolve expression of varying parameters

Tags: python, function, expression

I aksed this question sometime back but possible could not explain. Trying again to explain it better.
Firstly, i have recently started coding python so please let me know if any other details required.

I have 2 excel tabs

one containing the expressions in format

> 1. ( ( 36 AND 17 ) AND 57 ) OR ( 270 )
> 2. ( 71 ) OR ( 41 AND 70 )
> 3. ( ( 35 AND 2 ) AND 64 ) OR ( 63 )
> 4. ( ( 37 ) AND 65 )
> 5. ( ( 0 ) AND 65 ) OR ( ( 36 AND 17 ) AND 67 ) OR ( 66 )
> 6. ( 68 )
> 7. ( 69 )
> 8. ( 292 ) OR ( 42 AND 74 ) OR ( 41 AND 75 )
> 9. ( 72 )

the other tab contains the values of these numbers  which are used to construct above listed expressions.Now i am trying to write a functionality where i can pass an expression from the above list and get is resolved.

Presently i was able to have a workaround by  joining the 2 excel tabs based on a common id --

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\i0853\\Downloads\\r4.xlsx')
```

`df3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Operands')`-- operands contains the individual number with values for e.g.

```
71 => (age < 15), 41 => gender='male', 70 => codes in(1,2,3)
```

so that the expression     ( 71 ) OR ( 41 AND 70 ) will become `(age<15) OR (gender='male' AND codes in(1,2,3)`

`df4 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Expression Operands')`-- this contains the expression as listed above.

Now , i am only able to merge the two dataframes `
df2['value_set']=df2['value_set_id']

df_valueset=pd.merge(df2, df3, on='value_set', how='right') .. i am able to store the resolved values in a panda list --- `oplistf=pd.concat([oplist1a,oplist2])` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cQyL.png).. i have attached the screenshot of how the oplistf looks like. it contains the resolve values of the numbers.
`

to create the complete expression i am using basic print statements

```
print (f"enrflg in {tuple(oplistf['S348'])} AND bfsdcd  in {tuple(oplistf['S349'])}")

print (f"enrflg in {tuple(oplistf['S348'])} AND bfsdcd  in {tuple(oplistf['S350'])}")

print (f"enrflg in {tuple(oplistf['S342'])} AND icd10  in {tuple(oplistf['S343'])}")

print (f" ra_factor {tuple(oplistf['S4'])} AND   {tuple(oplistf['S2'])}")
```

My requirements is to write a generic function so that i can get any expression resolved . Presently i have to separately write individual print statements to resolve a single expression

Comment: If you are required to generate corresponding expression for this numerical input just keep a mapping of second csv in a dict and parse integer for final output, do this in a loop so that all expression are evaluated no manual step then. If this is your query then I can help you further? So something like,         ( 68 )      will get converted to.   ( YOUR_MAPPING_FOR_68)

Comment: In the excel that i have there are about 600 unique expression with different combinations of the numbers that themselves have some values... So do i need to line 600 lines of python statements to resolve each expression or is it possible to have pass the expression as some parameter.  Fo example if i pass "(17 and 34)" as as parameters then  the output is the expression that these number resolve to .. if 17==> age>15 and 34 ==> gender='f' then in the output the  expression should resolve to  (age > 15 and gender='f')

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if you need help with generateMapping method just add in comment will be happy to help :)

```py
DATA_FROM_CSV_1 = [
  ...
  "( 292 ) OR ( 42 AND 74 ) OR ( 41 AND 75 )",
  ...
] # expressions in an array loaded


DATA_FROM_CSV_2 = {
  ...
  292: "ABC",
  42: "DEF",
  ...
} # mapping of corrseponding number loaded

def generateMapping(exp):
  # assume you have a single exp and write code to convert and return
  ...
  return FINAL_STRING # ( converted expression )

for expression in DATA_FROM_CSV_1:
  print(generateMapping(expression))
```

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to work on this using an alternate approach--
i transposed the dataframe columns so that the numbers in the column become the column themselves and their resolved value are now their values so each column as ha single value..

````
exv= oplistf.to_frame().transpose()
all_columns = list(exv) # Creates list of all column headers
exv[all_columns] = exv[all_columns].astype(str)


so that i am able to write the expression by calling the numbers directly as column which will ultimately resolve to its value .
For example ,one of  the expression given in the column is :
'( ( 36 AND 17 ) AND 187 ) OR ( 188 )' . Now to resolve it i am using 

exp1=(exv['36'] + 'AND'  +  exv['17'] + 'AND' + exv['187'] + 'OR' + exv['188'])```

so that exp1 resolves to 
```0
['15 >= age']AND['999 <= age']AND['g301']OR['g309', 'g300', 'g308']

but still i have a tedious task of adding  + , 'AND' and 'OR'  manually to concatenate the individual subexpression and construct the complete expression. Can any expert here guide me on how to get a solution to this so that this concatenation of 'AND' and 'OR' can be taken care of in a better way ..
````